# VS 2013 cannot login to AccuRev with 2014.3 plugin

Tags: accurev

Everything worked fine with VS 2010 and Accubridge plugin. After installing VS 2013 and "AccuRev-plugin-for-visualstudiope-2014" plugin and configuring it, when logging into AccuRev, it doesn't actually log me in. Most of the options in the AccuRev menu stay greyed out now.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug with it. I to had an issue, where it would not login and would not allow be to edit the URI for the website or the location of accurev.exe.

I do not think there is any work being done on it now. You could create a .bat to run on successful build, to Keep to your workstation.

I switched to git locally and then run a bat at the end of day to push back to the streams.

just my two sense.

Comment: I was wondering if that might be the case, especially since there is no problem logging into the AccuRev client itself.